# Multiple Websites on 443 on same IP on WebFarm IIS8

Tags: iis-8

I have a 2 VM's

- WS1   -- IIS8 (one IP 167.158.90.20)

  - (site1.dm.com:443, SNI=True, Certificate=site1.dm.com HostName=site1.dm.com)
  - (site2.dm.com:443, SNI=True, Certificate=site2.dm.com HostName=site2.dm.com)
  - (site3.dm.com:443, SNI=True, Certificate=site3.dm.com HostName=site3.dm.com)
- WS2   -- IIS8 (one IP 167.158.90.10)

  - (site1.dm.com:443, SNI=True, Certificate=site1.dm.com HostName=site1.dm.com)
  - (site2.dm.com:443, SNI=True, Certificate=site2.dm.com HostName=site2.dm.com)
  - (site3.dm.com:443, SNI=True, Certificate=site3.dm.com HostName=site3.dm.com)

Now there is a F5 load balancer in front of it.

How can I test this now without going to load balancer Say

I want to hit site1

https://167.158.90.10/Transient/Keepalive.htm (site1)
https://167.158.90.20/Transient/Keepalive.htm (site1)

I want to hit site2

https://167.158.90.10/Transient/Keepalive.htm (site2)
https://167.158.90.20/Transient/Keepalive.htm (site2)

I want to hit site3

https://167.158.90.10/Transient/Keepalive.htm (site3)
https://167.158.90.20/Transient/Keepalive.htm (site3)

I want to individually hit the sites and receive a 200 status code.

Is this possible or do I need multiple IP's

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration/testing is off-topic.

Comment: Where should I move it to?

Comment: Perhaps you can set an entry for the hostname and IP in the hosts file, did you try? Just for testing...

Answer (score 0):

Make an entry for each host name <-> IP mapping.

> 167.158.90.10 site1.dm.com
>   167.158.90.20 site2.dm.com

And in the browser type the hostname.

> http://www.site1.dm.com

If you want the other server just change the IP in the hosts file for the respective entry.

Don't forget to call ipconfig /flushdns (can take some time to be propagated) after you change the hosts file for propagation reasons.